# Issue executing Ansible playbook on all of my hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following directory structure for some playbooks/inventory files on an Ansible controller:

```
playbooks
ansible.cfg
common_inventory
servers.yml
roles/
    check_services/
        tasks/
        handlers/
        library/
        files/
        templates/
        vars/
        defaults/
        meta/
```

This is the playbook I am trying to run:

```
---
- name: Check services status
  hosts:  win_domain,win_workgroup
  roles:
    - check_services
```

`common_inventory` is a file I am using to run servers.yml on a specific inventory like so:

`ansible-playbook -i common_inventory servers.yml`

`common_inventory` is written the following way:

```
[win_domain]
10.1.2.3
10.1.2.4

[win_workgroup]
10.1.2.5
10.1.2.6
```

At the moment, I have the group variables for all hosts in `roles/check_services/vars/main.yml` like so:

```
ansible_user: 'WINDOMAIN\ansmgmt'
ansible_password: 'Ansa123!'
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: credssp
ansible_port: '5986'
ansible_winrm_scheme: 'https'
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: 'ignore'
ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 60
ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 70
```

The problem I am having is that since a domain account is being used for `ansible_user`, it cannot be used for the non-domain targets in `win_workgroup`, therefore the targets are unreachable when the playbook runs.

So far I've tried making `common_inv` the inventory file in `ansible.cfg` and using group vars within common_inv to get around this issue.

```
[win_domain]
10.1.2.3
10.1.2.4

[win_workgroup]
10.1.2.5
10.1.2.6

[win_domain:vars]
ansible_user: 'WINDOMAIN\ansmgmt'
ansible_password: 'Ansa123!'
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: credssp
ansible_port: '5986'
ansible_winrm_scheme: 'https'
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: 'ignore'
ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 60
ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 70

[win_workgroup:vars]
ansible_user: 'ansalocal'
ansible_password: 'Welcome!1'
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: credssp
ansible_port: '5986'
ansible_winrm_scheme: 'https'
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: 'ignore'
ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 60
ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 70
```

After this, I deleted the connection information above from `vars/main.yml`.

Doing this gave me an error message saying that ansible could not connect to targets via ssh (which is odd because `ansible_connection` was set to winrm).

I am wondering if there is a different approach I can take to have the workgroup targets be reachable using a different `ansible_user`.

Comment: Have you already tried giving it an explicit playbook keyword `connection: winrm` or via the command-line `ansible-playbook -c winrm`? I hear you about the inventory items having `ansible_connection:` but it's likely worth a try with one of the work-arounds

Comment: Is it possible to set group vars on the playbook level? perhaps this could be done as a workaround but I haven't been able to find any documentation to do this.

Comment: No, group vars only apply to the hosts in the group; you're welcome to have group vars for `all` which is practically the same as "on the playbook level" but if all the hosts in your playbook are all using winrm, using `-c winrm` or `connection: winrm` is semantically accurate, as well as perhaps informing ansible what's going on